# Asking former manager to start 1-1 mentoring with me

Tags: management, mentoring

My former manager left our company a year ago to pursue another opportunity. He was an excellent manager and a great mentor.

I feel like my personal growth is slowing down without his mentorship. I'd really like to reach out and ask if he would continue being a mentor to me.

Two questions:

1. Is this an appropriate thing to do?
2. What should I offer in return? I can offer to pay him an hourly rate etc but I don't want to offend him by offering him money. I'm sure he doesn't need any more money, it would just be a token gesture so he's not giving me his time for free.

Comment: I don't feel like asking would be any bad. But a lot of context is missing, what industry, management? Why is his departure slowing you down in any way? And also has he been replaced? If so it might be good to check with his replacement first.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on a lot of things.

A lot of people reach out to old colleagues every once in a while.

Many folks will mentor for free. It should be symbiotic because they get the reassurance their knowledge and experience is valued, plus sometimes verbalizing things and telling other people helps you to better understand yourself.

I'd suggest reaching out to make small talk at first and then ask for a hand because you value and respect them.